# How to change the Export Value of an existing PDF checkbox with iText

Tags: c#, pdf, checkbox, itext

I've found a good example which shows how to set the checkbox export value (among other properties) for a new checkbox here (see the "CreateCheckBoxList" example):

https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/itextsharp-creating-form-fields/

However I need to change the export value for an existing checkbox. I tried modifying the above example in several different ways but nothing worked.

Just to clarify, the image below shows the checkbox property which I wish to change programmatically using iText:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `"on"` in `new RadioCheckField(writer, _rect, LANGUAGES_gc[i], "on")` and the `"On"` in `_Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", onOff[1]);`? (Actually I'm surprised those values differ in that example...)

Comment: Yes I did. Replacing `"On"` in `_Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", onOff[1]);`  with `"Yes"`will have the effect of changing the export value of the checkbox to `Yes`, which is basically what I'm after. However I need to do this with a PDF field that already exists (whereas the said example adds the export value to a new field that's being created). If I could somehow set `_checkbox1` to an existing PDF checkbox (and not to a new field `new RadioCheckField(writer, _rect, LANGUAGES_gc[i], "on");` I think that might work. But I just can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that word "existing" when reading your question.

Comment: The reason why I want to change the checkbox export value is because I have a web application which selects the PDF checkboxes based on some criteria and then generates a PDF file. In order to do that, I need to know ahead of time what the export value of all checkboxes in the PDF file will be (there are different kinds of PDF files, with potentially different export values set) or otherwise the web application will not be able to select the checkboxes.

Comment: As I'm still unable to change the export value, I decided to use a different approach which is to get the export value for each checkbox found in the PDF file, and then saved the "name/export value" pairs in my database. Then if I need to select a checkbox in a PDF, I simply look up the checkbox name in the database, get its export value, and finally select it.

Comment: Here is the code I use to get the export values for all checkboxes in a PDF file:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\test.pdf");
AcroFields fields = reader.AcroFields;

int i = 0;
string checkboxExportValues = "Count\tName\tExport Value\r\n";

//loop all fields in the pdf    
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kpv in fields.Fields)
{
    string exportValue = "";
    switch (fields.GetFieldType(kpv.Key))
    {
        //if the field is a checkbox, get the field's name and export value
        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
            AcroFields checkbox = reader.AcroFields;
            String[] values = checkbox.GetAppearanceStates(kpv.Key);

            //get the last checkbox state, which represents a selected checkbox
            foreach (String value in values)
            {
                exportValue = value;
            }
            checkboxExportValues = checkboxExportValues + i + "\t" + kpv.Key + "\t" + exportValue + "\r\n";
        break;
   }
   i++;
}
reader.Close();
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\exportValues.txt", checkboxExportValues);

/*
Sample output:
Count    Name    Export Value
1    Check Box106    Yes
2    Check Box107    Yes
3    Check Box122    1
4    Check Box127    On
5    Check Box128    2
*/
```

Comment: I would still prefer to be able to change the export values of the checkboxes in the PDF programmatically, since saving the "name/export value" pairs in the database for each different type of PDF files presents an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same requirement and found your post. Since I didn't find anything related I implemented it myself. Unfortunatly it is in Java but you might be able to translate it to C#. Be aware that:

- I shortened the code for better viewability - you have to add your own error handling etc.
- I assume that a checkbox has two appearances: (1) for the unchecked state (/Off) and one for the checked state (2) which can be freely chosen
- You might have to change the /Opt array as well if it exists

So here is the code:

```
[...]

case (AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX):

 PdfDictionary ap = item.getWidget(i).getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
 if (ap != null) {
    PdfDictionary normalAp = ap.getAsDict(PdfName.N);
    changeAppearanceStateNames(normalAp, "NewExportValue", "Check Box106");

    PdfDictionary downAp = ap.getAsDict(PdfName.D);
    changeAppearanceStateNames(downAp, "NewExportValue", "Check Box106"););

    PdfDictionary rolloverAp = ap.getAsDict(PdfName.R);
    changeAppearanceStateNames(rolloverAp, "NewExportValue", "Check Box106");
 }
break; [...]

private void changeAppearanceStateNames(PdfDictionary appearanceSubdictionary, String newValue, String fieldname) throws NotSpecCompliantException {
    if (appearanceSubdictionary != null) {
        if(appearanceSubdictionary.size()>2) throw Exception ...

        String appearanceSubDictionaryName=null;

        //detect name for the checked value
        for(Object key : appearanceSubdictionary.getKeys()) {
            String name = PdfName.decodeName(((PdfName)key).toString());

            if(!name.equals("Off")) {
                appearanceSubDictionaryName=name;
            }
        }

        //update it
        if(appearanceSubDictionaryName!=null) {
            PdfObject appearanceSubDictionaryValue = appearanceSubdictionary.get(new PdfName(appearanceSubDictionaryName));
            appearanceSubdictionary.remove(new PdfName(appearanceSubDictionaryName));
            appearanceSubdictionary.put(new PdfName(newValue),appearanceSubDictionaryValue);
        }
        //else {
            //theoretically create a new appearance here. Details can be seen in the #RadioCheckField
            //however since only the export value should be changed it is assumed that the actual appearance dictionary does already exists
        //}
    }
}
```